# tiptap: make isEmpty return true when the editor only contains whitespaces and new lines (LITERALLY empty)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tiptap

this isEmpty still returns true when the editor contains only whitespace(s) (and alongside with new lines) :

```js
import { EditorContent, Editor } from "@tiptap/vue-3";

const editor = new Editor({
  // ...
})

const isEmpty = () => !editor.state.doc.textContent.length;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-vue-forked-gpwrpn

P.S. I don't use `editor.isEmpty` because it's unreliable, views whitespaces and new lines as not empty

Comment: You might have a point about meaningful vs irrelevant content but a string with whitespace is not an empty string and the fact that it doesn't work the way *you* want it to does not mean it's "unreliable".

Comment: @JaredSmith understood it but in this context, it's unreliable

Comment: Ah I gotcha, you mean you can't rely on it for your purpose. Generally though when I hear somebody say that a tool is unreliable they mean that its behavior *changes* somewhat unpredictably, e.g. the output of `ls` is unreliable as it changes across versions/platforms/implementations. The behavior of the built-in editor.isEmpty is completely deterministic even though it doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method on your textContent :

```js
const isEmpty = () => !editor.state.doc.textContent.trim().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This (`editor.state.doc.textContent.trim().length`) will work when your editor only has text nodes, but it will fail when the editor has atom nodes like images and mentions, as mentioned in this Github [comment](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/580#issuecomment-826398844).

To check whether the editor is **truly** empty or not, you should implement a custom function that cycles through all the nodes and checks whether a node of that type is empty or not.

Here is a good starting point:

```js
function isContentBlockEmpty(block) {
    if (!block || !block.type) {
        return true
    }

    if (block.type in SOME_CUSTOM_OBJECT) {
        return SOME_CUSTOM_OBJECT[block.type](block)
    }

    if ('text' in block) {
        return !block.text?.trim()
    }

    return block.content ? block.content.every((_block) => isContentBlockEmpty(_block)) : true
}
```

And you can call this function, like this: `isContentBlockEmpty(editor.getJSON())`